# Couchdb add user database configuration

Tags: couchdb

I want to use Couchdb to create a offline first app, where users can add documents.

Only the user who created a document should be able to change it, otherwise it should only be readable. For this i wanted to use the "peruser" mechanism of couchdb and replicate these documents into a main database where everyone can read.

Is it possible to automatically get the replication and other configurations (like design documents) configured when the database is created by the [couch_peruser options](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/config/couch-peruser.html?highlight=peruser)?

Comment: What is `official peruser plugin`?

Comment: Maybe my wording is wrong. I mean this feature: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/config/couch-peruser.html?highlight=peruser

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible way myself:

- add a validation function to the main database to deny writes (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/ddocs.html#vdufun)
- use `_db_updates` endpoint to monitor database creation (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/server/common.html#db-updates)
- create a `_replicator` document to set up a continuous replication from userdb to main db (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/replication/replicator.html)

One thing to look about is that maintaining a lot of continuous replications requires a lot of system resources.

Another way is to create authorships with design documents. With this aproach we don't need to maintain replications to the main database, because every entry can be hold in one database (main database in my case).

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/validation.html#authorship